# How can i change scroll bar track color from a set position?

Tags: c#

I have two horizontal scroll bars and they move together, My two documents are different widths.

The scroll bar that will not scroll all the way must have red highlighting on the position it wont affect the web browsers scrolling.

In the picture below the right hand web browser is at its full webBrowser2Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Right but the left had browser can still scroll more.

So when a web browser position reaches webBrowser2Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Right, how can i turn the remaining track red?

Or even better how can i set a portion of the track color to be red from a position on wards.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use XAML for your GUI, I would suggest making a new style for the ScrollBar based on this one:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173.aspx

Change the style of the Track.IncreaseRepeatButton to use a new style that sets red as the foreground color.